# How do i disable Run | Debug option coming in java main class file in Visual Studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Whenever I am writing java program with main class(public static void main) it shows Run | Debug option in visual studio code. How can i hide or disable this from coming?

I can run using F5 or Run java file so wanted to get rid of this.

see below:

[image]

Comment: have you looked in the settings? The are called Codelens

Comment: @rioV8

I was not aware of any codelens option being new to Visual studio code world. I searched codelens, disabled that setting and it worked. thank you so much.

Comment: I have disabled them everywhere but the python unit test files, handy to run a single test or group of tests

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for that python info. That means when i need to write and test my Junit test cases, that time I can enable this feature or if similiar requirement. Rest, I can continue to hide it.

I am eclipse IDE guy and believe that hiding it is better from code perspective for any project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable codelens option in vs code settings and it worked.
This solution is suggested by @rioV8.

[image]